# Missing flaw in finding all integers satisfying $\varphi(n)=n/2$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, totient-function

I was reading this book on analytic number theory by Tom M. Apostol, and I came across this problem that asks for all integers that satisfy the following equality:

> $$ \varphi(n) = n/2$$

where $\varphi$ is the the Euler totient function.

This was my first attempt:

$$\varphi(n) =( N * \mu )(n)$$

$$\implies u * (N * \mu) =  \varphi * u = N$$

But the numbers we are looking for should fulfill $\varphi(n) = n/2$, therefore the following proposition should be true for these numbers.

$$N = \frac{1}{2}N*u $$

$$\implies N(n) = (\frac{1}{2}N*u)(n)$$

$$ \implies n = \sum_{d|n}\frac{1}{2}d$$

$$ \implies n =  \sum_{d|n,d\neq n}d$$

where $*$ is the Dirichlet multiplication, $\mu$ is the mobius function  of order 1, $N(n) = n, u(n) = 1 ,\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$

which means the solution is all perfect numbers, but obviously one can disprove it by verification.

**Somehow I managed to find the correct  solution using another way. But I couldn't  find out what I missed on my first attempt. Can some one help me  figure out what it is ?** Thanks.

Comment: Your first attempt is pretty much incomprehensible. I take it that $\mu$ is the Mobius $\mu$-function, and that your first equation is the way you have chosen to write $\phi(n)=(N*\mu)(n)$, where the star represents arithmetic convolution. Then your second equation is not an identity, but an assumption: *suppose* $(N*\mu)(n)=N(n)/2$.  Now, is $u(n)$ the function that is one for all $n$, or is it the function that is one when $n=1$ and zero for all other $n$? I think there may be some confusion here.

Comment: why does it follow from $f(n_0)=g(n_0)$ that $h*f(n_0)=h*g(n_0)$?? Taking convolution involves multiple values not only the ones at $n_0$

Comment: @Conrad I am reading this college book by myself so help me out here if i am wrong, it says that the set of arithmetic functions form a group under the operation $*$, and don't the properties of groups (that if $a,b$ and $u$ are in group $G$ under some arbitrary operation $*$, and if $a =b$, then $a*u = b*u$) apply here as $f$ and $g$ are elements of that group ?

Comment: The point is that you do not have an equality of arithmetic functions since that means $f(n)=g(n)$ for *all* $n$. Here you just have equality at a point (some points); if it helps think like this $x=x^2$ for $x=0,1$ but taking derivatives it is not true anymore that those are equal there - convolution is more like an integral but the same point applies as convolution also depends on many values of the functions in cause

Comment: @Conrad Thanks, I see my oversight now.

Comment: Great and happy to be of help

Answer (score 8):

$n$ has to be even, because $\varphi(n)$ must be an integer. Once $n$ is even, naturally all $n/2$ even numbers below it are not co-prime with $n$, which gives $\varphi(n) \leq \frac{n}{2}$. To have equality, we must ensure that all the odd numbers below $n$ are also coprime with it. Thus, $n$ must be a power of $2$.

Comment: Thanks, my second attempt resembles a lot like yours. But I am looking for the flaw on the solution I have described(my first attempt).